# Repeating subtrees using python

Tags: python, html, tree, subtree

I need to find whether there is a structure similarity with in an HTML file. So, I tried to match the html file to a tree structure. Then, I want to find whether a tree contains repeating subtrees using python. I also want to find those subtrees also. How can we do this process using python?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer, that using BeautifulSoup in python. BeautifulSoup gives the parsed html to tree structure, and i just crawled through the children and find the similarity between the tags in subtrees.